# CakePHP branch routing

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, controller, url-routing

I am trying to test some new features on a live site.

My goal is to have a prefix ('dev', for example) and have that prefix display the complete site with default actions, except those I define as dev_{action_name}.

Example:

```
/dev/orders/create
```

Seeks for OrdersController::dev_create() action, if not found, uses OrdersController::create().

So far, I managed to make a standard 'dev' prefix with the Router and put some beforeFilter magic like:

```
<?php
//bootstrap.php code:
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'dev'));

// AppController::beforeFilter() code:
if (preg_match('/^dev_(.*)$/', $this->params['action'], $subs)){
   $new_action = $subs[1];
   if (method_exists($this, $new_action)){
          $this->params['action'] = $new_action;
    } 
}
?>
```

This works as expected, except the complete Routing schema is not copied to "dev", which means all the links are rendered without the "dev prefix and my custom routes are disregarded.

I thought about fixing it with .htaccess rule and putting a dev=true in the query string:

```
#webroot/.htaccess
RewriteRule ^dev(.*)$ index.php?dev=true&%{QUERY_STRING}
#... rewrite conds ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L] #original Cake rewrite
```

But this yielded no results (Cake was still parsing the original URL, not the re-written).

Is there a "right" way of doing this?

Comment: In essence, I have to copy the entire site to a sub-route and handle the "exception" methods "by hand".

Comment: Whoa whoa. You're making this much more complicated than necessary. The prefix is stored in in `$this->request->prefix` so no need for regex. Also, don't touch the htaccess as Cake's routing takes care of it. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: Also interesting question, I don't think I've come across it before. I'd change the title something like "CakePHP prefix action fallback" - a little more specific to your question.

Comment: This was my initial solution, but it asserts that we have to copy all the actions+views to dev_* and copy all the routes to /dev/* which defies the purpose of having a working copy of the site with some development actions. It would result in a complex routing schema and fat controllers, just to have 4 new actions tested? Too much work + maintenance.

What I'm after is actually a kind of "site branching" system - when you wish to "merge-in" /dev/ to main, just rename dev_action to action, and you're done!

Comment: Using a prefix makes other prefixes useless (you cannot have two prefixes at once) and I have admin, moderator and customer prefixes which need to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully achieved this with CakePHP 2.2.1. It's ugly, it's long, it's against the rules, but it works! :D

file: **/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ $1 //my hack
    //      /dev/orders/create => /orders/create 
    //      /dev/css/main.css => /css/main.css
    // This only changes the url for the next rule
    // Cake would have still parsed /dev/orders/create
    // but this is needed for the sake of static files in app/webroot
//cake native rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

file: **bootstrap.php**

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : ''; 
    //$url is still /dev/orders/create, despite the rewrites

Configure::write('App.dev', false); 
//we use this to check if we're in "dev" mode
//anywhere in the app, just call: 
    //  if ( Configure::read('App.dev') ) ...

//check if URL starts with /dev
if (preg_match('|^/dev|', $url)){ 
    /* the most important thing is to trick CakePHP
    into thinking it's on a /dev/ subfolder on the server
    this preserves all the routing as it 
            should be, not making it prefixed route */
    Configure::write('App.base', '/dev');
    Configure::write('App.dev', true);
    //this changes /dev/orders/create to /orders/create 
            //for Cake's Route parser
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace('|/dev|', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
}
?>
```

At this point, we have all that we need to have CakePHP display a complete copy of the site under /dev/.
Cake does all the default actions+views, all links work as expected (as long as you use helpers for URLs), all static files get served.
All app paths and constants remain intact.

Now for some method magic:

```
<?php
//file: AppController.php
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request) {

    if (Configure::read('App.dev')) {
        $new_action = 'dev'.$request->params['action'];
        if (method_exists($this, $new_action)){
            $request->params['action'] = $new_action;
        }
    }


    return parent::invokeAction($request);
}
?>
```

All of this enables us to:

- Have a complete working alias of the site on /dev/, which includes routes, prefixes, static files, database connections, etc.
- Override an ACTION using "dev" in front of the name.
- Have a single switch for "dev" or "not dev" (App.dev config)

For instance:

```
<?php
//OrdersController.php

//gets called on /admin/orders/view
public function admin_view(){} 

//gets called on /dev/admin/orders/view
public function devadmin_view(){ 
    //views have to be defined manually for DEV actions
    $this->render('devadmin_view'); 
}

//gets called on /admin/orders/add 
//            AND /dev/admin/orders/add
public function admin_add() {} 

?>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you wanted *double* prefixes. Hm. Bet that's going to be fun to maintain down the road :) Good luck! Glad you got it working how you want.

Comment: Yeah, the "action-replacement" is an accident waiting to happen. But I just need the bank people to review my CreditCard implementation solution and then it's back to "normal" operation mode.

Comment: But you definitely got me thinking about writing a "standardized" package to support Cake versioning. Thanks Jeremy! Do you mind if I borrow the name "double prefixes" ? :D

Comment: Haha go for it. I think it would lead to a lot of complications especially with plugins, but maybe not!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to do what you want. Before invoking the action it checks if it exists and if not falls back to the original action. If you did it later exceptions would be raised since the action doesn't exist.

There may be more to it but this is a start.

```
// need to override invokeAction
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request) {
  if ($request->prefix == 'dev') {
    if (!method_exists($request->action)) {
      $request->action = str_replace($request->prefix.'_', '', $request->action);
      $request->prefix = null;
    }
  }
  return parent::invokeAction($request);
}
```

Comment: After 4 hours of digging through Cake core libraries, that is pretty much exactly how my AppController::invokeAction looks like :D